# Dovecot domain part empty

Tags: postfix, email, dovecot

I have a Postfix-Dovecot setup up and running. Today I added a new domain, so i had to change the mail setup to serve it. The Postfix installation is running well now: The mails are delivered to

```
/var/mail/<domain>/<userpart>
```

Unfortunately, Dovecot is not able to retrieve the domain-part and hence cannot get mails. I find messages like this in the logs:

```
Nov 12 10:58:10 gondwana dovecot: IMAP(so): mkdir(/var/mail//so/cur) failed: Permission denied
```

In the namespace part of dovecot, I have:

```
namespace private {
   separator = /
   prefix = INBOX/
   location = maildir:/var/mail/%d/%n
   inbox = yes
}
```

Any ideas=

Comment: Got the same problem and would very much like to hear the details of the resultion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems incomplete, but I'm going to take a wild guess : you're not using virtual users, and not authenticating users with the domain part in their logins. [Read this](http://wiki.dovecot.org/VirtualUsers).

If this is not the right answer to your issue, then we're going to need more info. Are you using virtual users ? Can you post the relevant part of your config file ? What are the login for of your users ? user@domain ?

Comment: you're right, and I was able to solve it now, thanks.